# How to import external css inside jsx file in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have to add the css file externally. Tried with the code import "./Login.css"; which is located in the base path. Cant able to get the file, which turns the error like below.

**You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.**

```
.Login {
         padding: 60px 0;
}
```

I updated in webpack config also.

Webpack config:

```
var config = {
   entry: './main.js',

   output: {
      path:'/',
      filename: 'index.js',
   },

   devServer: {
      inline: true,
      port: 8080
   },

   module: {
      loaders: [
      {
      test: /\.css$/,  
      include: /node_modules/,  
      loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
 },
         {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',

            query: {
               presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}

module.exports = config;
```

In JSX File:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, FormGroup, FormControl, ControlLabel } from "react-bootstrap"; 
import "./Login.css";
```

**Package.json,**

```
{
  "name": "reactapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Tetser",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1"
  }
}
```

I tried atmost everything, but no solution. Anyone clarify, please.

Comment: this is working for me `{ test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" }`

Comment: you can link it to you html file

Comment: added package.json file@Liam

Comment: Getting same error @MikeKor

Comment: want to import in some components only @EgorEgorov

Comment: I'm not seeing babel-loader and babel-preset-es2015 installed in your dependencies, how did you install them?

Answer (score 3):

You will need to add css-loader and style-loader to your dev dependencies in package.json

Link to webpack docs:
https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/#using-loaders

Answer (score 1):

The way I do it (ex: import fonts from fonts.com) :

- create a css file,
- import external css in local css file
- import local css file in js

Comment: +1 because although a bit clunky feeling, it sidesteps the hours of frustration one might get trying to import a cdn css directly into a jsx file. You should add code example for each file here.